# javascript variable new scope inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

My program has the following $.each loop:

```js
    var uiData = {};
    $.each(disciplines, function(key, discipline) {
        var cacheKey = getCacheKey(discipline, from, to, type);
        // http://www.2ality.com/2011/02/javascript-variable-scoping-and-its.html
        // http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch16.html#inadvertently_sharing_environments
        success = (function(_d) {
            var __d = _d;
            return function(data) {                    
                if (!(data instanceof Graph)) {
                    data = new Graph(data['vertices'], data['edges']);
                    graphs[cacheKey] = data;
                }
                uiData[__d] = data.getVertices().length;
                graph.merge(data, mergeRecursiveInto, mergeRecursiveInto);
            };
        }(discipline));

        if (cacheKey in graphs) {
            // timeout is necessary, to simulate an ajax-call to give the browser time to show the loading - dialog
            setTimeout(function () {
                barrier.waitOn(success)(graphs[cacheKey])
            }, 50);

        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : jsonUrls[type],
                data : {
                    d : [ discipline ],
                    from : yearFrom,
                    to : yearTo
                },
                success: barrier.waitOn(success)                                
            });  
        }
    });
```

What I expect is, that for every iteration, should be an separate success-function generated with a `discipline`. I read the two mentioned links and thought I understand it, but my debugger said something else. The IIFE won't snapshot the discipline.
So what is the problem, what did I miss?

Comment: you haven't declared success, so that is getting overwritten.

Comment: Where is `success` defined? Is there a `var success` in the parent scope? Otherwise, `success` will be defined as a global variable which will get overwritten on each iteration. Placing a `var` in front of `success =` will fix this problem, if it indeed is the case.

Comment: You are so right. It is the second time in one week, that this falling me to the feet. No, I forget it :(.

Comment: Ok, one question out of the row. Why everybody only post the answer as comment, not as real answer? Is the second question where this happens, so is this something special?

Answer (score 0):

Like Daniel A. White and musically_ut said, I forget to define success.

`var success = ...` solved the problem.

Thanks to all.